# How to modify selenium xpath with python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[3]").text
```

instead of this, I want something like

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[",i,"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[3]").text
```

this to increase `i` in a loop. But when I use this one the error message I have is this

> "InvalidSelectorException: Message: Invalid locator values passed in"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong syntax for string concatenation. Try substituting in the value of `i` instead:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[%d]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[3]" % i).text
```

Comment: @zahedae it works when printing because `print()` accepts multiple arguments, and concatenates them behind the scenes. For everything else, you need to use one of `string1 + string2`, `"foo" + "bar"`, `" ".join(string1, string2)`, `"foo %s bar" % "baz"`, the `str.format()` method, and probably some others I've missed. Google python string concatenation and string formatting for more info